Как сделать так, чтобы при копировании текста с сайта, текст копировался с нестандартным шрифтом?
Хочу сделать похожий сайт (https://textgenerator.ru/), но столкнулся с проблемой. При копировании текст копируется со стандартным шрифтом.
<textarea id="copyword" class="post" readonly></textarea>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap');
.post{
  font-family: Pacifico;
}


Никак. Стили скопируются, но откуда же возьмётся нестандартный шрифт вне сайта на котором его подключили?

@Alexey Ten, а как остаётся шрифт скопированный с сайта, на который я оставил ссылку?

Там нет шрифтов. Там используются экзотические символы из юникода. Например https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumeric_Supplement#

@Alexey Ten, ясно. А можете подсказать, как их подключать?
